# How to fix state change issue which work one step behind onClick event

Tags: reactjs

I want change state by click but it work one step behind. I don`t understand what`s wrong.

```
class Products extends Component {        
    state = {
            product: null
        }

    render() {       
        const handalebar = (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            const product_code = event.target.closest('.card').getAttribute('id');

            this.setState({
                product: product_code
            })                

            console.log(this.state.product);
        }
```

Comment: You need to include a complete example. In the code above `product_code` has not been defined, `handlebar` is not being used, and your `render` function doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setState is asynchronous, use the callback to log the updated state:

```
setState(
  { product: product_code },
  () => console.log(this.state.product)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write handlebar function outside the render function and put state object in constructor and don't forget to bind the function.

```
class Products extends Component{
                constructor(props){
                      super(props)
                      this.state = {
                               product: null
                              }
                      this.handlebar = this.handlebar.bind(this);
                 }


     handlebar = (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            const product_code = event.target.value;

            this.setState({
                product: product_code
            })                

           render(){
               console.log(this.state.product);
           return (
                    <div>
                    </div>
           )
}
}
```

Comment: Why would you use an arrow function *and* bind it in the ctor?

Comment: What do you want exactly?

Comment: I want to know why you're binding an arrow function.